# Reactor-netty is reserving file descriptors for the whole pool (eventfd, timerfd, eventpoll)

Tags: java, httpclient, netty, webclient, reactor-netty

I have a problem with increased number of file descriptors after moving to WebClient that uses netty-reactor, httpclient and epoll on Unix. From what I've found, Netty is creating a pool of threads to maintain connections, each of these epoll event executors creates three file descriptors - eventfd, timerfd and eventpoll. Because of that, if my CPU has 32 cores, then there are 96 file descriptors per application and they are always opened, even if not used (because they are created immediately after first request). What is the reason not to create these FDs lazily or even fill the pool lazily?
Thank you!

I tried to analyze the issue with too many open files on our servers after moving to WebClient.